# How to draw stacked bargraph in ggplot for data type list?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw stacked bar graph for the data in R

```
   alc    sex count
  <lgl> <fctr> <int>
1 FALSE   Male  5537
2 FALSE Female 11555
3  TRUE   Male  6989
4  TRUE Female  8150
```

I tried running this code :

```
ggplot(data = x_dat , aes(x = sex , y = count)) + geom_histogram()
```

> Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`

I cant go any further. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Do you need `geom_bar` i.e. `ggplot(x_dat, aes(x = sex, y = count)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: Please clarify as you have each `sex` twice.  Do you want the stacking by `alc` ?  If so, you may want to modify @akrun 's post to have `fill` as in `ggplot(data = x_dat , aes(x = sex, y = count, fill = alc)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a stacked barplot easily with `base R`

```
barplot(xtabs(count~alc + sex, x_dat), col = c("red", "blue"), legend = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
x_dat <- structure(list(alc = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), sex = c("Male", 
 "Female", "Male", "Female"), count = c(5537L, 11555L, 6989L, 
8150L)), .Names = c("alc", "sex", "count"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```